# Python Break but return or store the current value

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, break

How do implement a for loop with a break that also returns the values at the break?

```
x = np.empty(1)

x[0] = 0.4

f = np.array([3,2,1,0,1,2,3])
y = np.empty(0)

for i in range(len(f)):
    if f[i+1] < f[i]:
        newx = x[i]*2
        y = np.append(y,f[i+1])
        x = np.append(x,newx)
    else:
        break
```

this returns y = [2,1,0] and x = [0.4,0.8,1.6,3.2] but I want it to return also the vales y = 1 and x = 6.4 which would be the next iteration.

Comment: `return` itself breaks the loop why you need explicit `break`

Comment: i guess you just need a print statement  :) before returning or breaking use print , let me know if you want to store it .. i will help you with the code

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. @AkshayNevrekar How would an explicit break work? (somewhat new to python here).

Comment: @PuneetSinha yes I'm storing the values!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for i in range(len(f) - 1):        
    newx = x[i]*2
    y = np.append(y,f[i+1])
    x = np.append(x,newx)

    if f[i+1] > f[i]:
        break
```

This snippet will also append the next iteration before breaking out of the loop.

Comment: Sweet ! This works. Thank you for the quick response. I guess it was a simple fix. Somewhat new to python plus being working on this project for too many hours already.

Comment: f[i+1] will trigger index error under some condition, which depends on the inputs

Comment: @MenglongLi Edited to go to `len(f) - 1` to avoid index error.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding code to your else block like this:

```
for i in range(len(f)):
    if f[i+1] < f[i]:
        newx = x[i]*2
        y = np.append(y,f[i+1])
        x = np.append(x,newx)
    else:
        y = np.append(y,f[i+1])
        x = np.append(x,newx)
        break
```

This may workout.

Comment: @MenglongLi Why? This has the same problem as my code originally had.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new condition.

```
x = np.empty(1)
x[0] = 0.4
f = np.array([3,2,1,0,1,2,3])
y = np.empty(0)
for i in range(len(f)):
    if f[i+1] < f[i]:
        newx = x[i]*2
        y = np.append(y,f[i+1])
        x = np.append(x,newx)
    elif f[i+1]>f[i] and f[i]==0:
        newx = x[i] * 2
        y = np.append(y, f[i + 1])
        x = np.append(x, newx)
    else:
        break
```